# Writing url without https remove slash

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

if i write url like this:
https://subdomain.domain.net/directory/
it works however, if I try to directly write in a browser: subdomain.domain.net/directory/ the browser trims the first slash and therefore could not load the page and the url looks like this: subdomain.domain.netdirecotry

I am using codeigniter, and have this in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, these days with CI3 your HTACCESS should be :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

And you might have some errors in your config.php be sure to set properly  the base_url with a trailing slash :

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://ci.app/';
```

and remove your index.php :

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Should be it.